# ControlTemplate Element also resizes when the Control Template where it was binded is resized - WPF XAML

Tags: wpf, visual-studio, xaml, controltemplate

I wanna know if its possible to resize an element inside a controlTemplate by resizing the Element which it was binded.

This is the code for the Button ControlTemplate:

```
    <ControlTemplate x:Name="normalButton" x:Key="roundedEdge" TargetType="Button">
        <Grid>
            <Rectangle Fill="{TemplateBinding Background}" RadiusX="16" RadiusY="16" Stroke="{TemplateBinding BorderBrush}" StrokeThickness="4"/>
            <Ellipse Width="38" Height="38" VerticalAlignment="Top" HorizontalAlignment="Center" Margin="0,12,0,0" Fill="{StaticResource tertiaryColor}"/>
            <ContentPresenter HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Bottom" Margin="0, 0, 0, 6"/>
        </Grid>
    </ControlTemplate>
```

and it is the controlTemplate is binded to the Button :

```
 <Button x:Name="button2_Copy2" Width="112" Height="80"Template="{StaticResource roundedEdge}""/>
```

If I resize the Button Control, the Ellipse in the ControlTemplate will also resize but its size must not be equal to the Button Control where it was binded.

Comment: The Ellipse won't resize as long as you set a fixed Width and Height. In order to have proportional resizing (if that is what you're asking), define appropriate Grid Rows and/or Columns.

Comment: @Clemens I defined some row and column definitions but it doesnt do anything.

Comment: We can't help you if you don't show your code, and if you don't clearly explain what you are trying to achieve.

Answer (score 0):

You can use Binding and Convert:

```
 <Window.Resources>
        <local:DoubleToDoubleConvert x:Key="DoubleToDoubleConvert"></local:DoubleToDoubleConvert>
        <ControlTemplate x:Name="normalButton" x:Key="roundedEdge" TargetType="Button">
            <Grid>
                <Rectangle  Fill="{TemplateBinding Background}" RadiusX="16" RadiusY="16" Stroke="{TemplateBinding BorderBrush}" StrokeThickness="4"/>
                <Ellipse  Width="{TemplateBinding Width ,Converter={StaticResource DoubleToDoubleConvert}}" Height="{TemplateBinding Height,Converter={StaticResource DoubleToDoubleConvert}}" VerticalAlignment="Top" HorizontalAlignment="Center" Margin="0,12,0,0" Fill="Red"/>
                <ContentPresenter HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Bottom" Margin="0, 0, 0, 6"/>

            </Grid>


        </ControlTemplate>
    </Window.Resources>


  public class DoubleToDoubleConvert : IValueConverter
    {

        public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
        {
            double reValue = System.Convert.ToInt32(value);
            return reValue / 3;
        }

        public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
        {
            double strValue = (double)value;
            return value;
        }
    }
```

Thanks.